# hiding/closing a div opened by .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my page loads I hide a div containing a form using

```
$('#popupPerson').hide();
```

then in the body I build a table and this popup to help insert/update/delete row data using a form that is initally hidden

```
<div id="popupPerson" class="popupPerson">
  <form id="form_popup_person" action="person_update" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Person</legend>
      <label for="id">id</label>&nbsp;<input name="id" type="number" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label for="revision">revision</label>&nbsp;<input name="revision" type="number" /><p>
      <label for="lastName">lastName</label>&nbsp;<input name="lastName" type="text" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label for="firstName">firstName</label>&nbsp;<input name="firstName" type="text" /><p>
      <label for="street">street</label>&nbsp;<input name="street" type="text" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label for="city">city</label>&nbsp;<input name="city" type="text" /><p>
      <label for="county">county</label>&nbsp;<input name="county" type="text" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <label for="state">state</label>&nbsp;<input name="state" type="text" />&nbsp;&nbsp;  
      <label for="postalCode">postalCode</label>&nbsp;<input name="postalCode" type="text" /><p>  
      <label for="birthDate">birthDate</label>&nbsp;<input name="birthDate" type="text" />&nbsp;&nbsp;  
      <label for="email">email</label>&nbsp;<input name="email" type="text" />&nbsp;&nbsp;       
      <label for="status">status</label>&nbsp;<input name="status" type="text" /><p> 
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <input name="cancel" type="submit" class="cancel" value="Cancel" />
      <button type="button" class="cancel" onClick="this.parent.close();">Cancel button</button>
      <button type="button" class="cancel" onClick="$(this).parent().parent().hide();">parent parent hide button</button>
      <button type="button" class="cancel" onClick="$(this).parent().hide();">parent hide button</button>  <!-- makes ALL BUTTONS DISAPPEAR -->
      <button type="button" class="cancel" onClick="$(this).hide();">hide button</button>         <!-- makes the BUTTON ITSELF DISAPPEAR -->       
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

and some js so that if a row in the table is clicked this fires and makes the div visible

```
$('#popupPerson').show();
```

I want to add a "Cancel" button to the form that simply closes/hides the div - no submitting, no resetting.

Comment: Why can you not use `$('#popupPerson').hide()` in the onclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply write like

```
 <button type="button" class="cancel" onClick="$('#popupPerson').hide();">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this: `<button type="button" class="cancel" onClick="$(this).closest('.popupPerson').hide();">parent parent hide button</button>` which closes the containing .popupPerson, incase you ever need more than one on a page.

Alternatively, you can put this in a script:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.popupPerson .cancel', function(){
    $(this).closest('.popupPerson').hide();
    // Do whatever else you want here, like eat the event (stopPropegation, etc).
  });
});
```

And this is the element:

```
<a class="cancel">parent parent hide button</a>
```